# Page break table with single cell

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have an environment set up of `longtables` that I use as "tips"-boxes and exercises in my book. The left column shows only one word rotated (tips, exercise or whatever) while the right contains the rest of the text. Now the problem is that the right column is a single cell so (xe)latex decides to put the table on a new page if it is too big. Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

So how can I make it start on the current page and break whenever necessary, then continue on the next page?

My code for the table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{%
  \parskip=0.5\baselineskip%
  \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
   \setlength{\parfillskip}{30pt plus 1fil}}m{#1}}

\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
{
    \begin{longtable}{m{0.05\textwidth}|M{0.85\textwidth}}
    \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Övning}} & \textbf{#1} \newline
}
{\end{longtable}
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{exercise}{1}
\lipsum
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Do you have to use a `longtable` or would you consider an answer involving `mdframed`?

Comment: @PeterGrill: updated with an MWE now,

Comment: @cmhughes: I never heard of mdframed, looking it up now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use longtable is such a combination. In the comment of [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) the package `mdframed` was recommended. In the example below you can find two possibilities with `mdframed`.

If you have further questions you can ask ;-)

**EDIT: CHANGED CODE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter


\newrobustcmd\Titleenv[1]{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=cc]{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
   \setlength\@tempdimc{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}
   \renewcommand*\md@@frametitle{%
      \llap{\smash{\raisebox{-.5\@tempdimc}{\box0}\hspace*{2em}}}}%
   \appto\md@frame@leftline@single{%
     \ifdimgreater{\mdfboundingboxheight}{\@tempdimc}%
     {}%
     {%
       \llap{\color{\mdf@middlelinecolor}%
           \rule[\dimexpr-.5\@tempdimc-\mdf@innerbottommargin@length\relax]%
                {\mdf@middlelinewidth@length}%
                {\dimexpr\@tempdimc+\mdf@innerbottommargin@length
                         +\mdf@innertopmargin@length\relax}%
            }%
     }%
   }%
}

\newenvironment{exercise}{%
  \mdfsetup{topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,linecolor=red,
          linewidth=2pt,skipbelow=\topskip,skipabove=\topskip}
   \Titleenv{\"Ovning}%
\begin{mdframed}[]%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
\lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{exercise}
Text
\end{exercise}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{exercise}
\lipsum
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

The code above results in the following picture:
[image]

Comment: it is better to call `tlmgr --self --all update` then the manager can update itself, too

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to have the line and vertical text inside the default text width

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}   
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
  {\par\begin{leftbar}\noindent\textbf{#1}\\
   \makebox(0,0){\put(-30,-50){\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Övning}}}}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{leftbar}\par}

\begin{document}    
\lipsum

\begin{exercise}{1}
\lipsum
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this option, and I had two problems: 1) I use lstlistings and it seems like the line numbers get in the way of the bar. 2): There seems to be spacing issues: http://i.imgur.com/FJxMI.png

Comment: give an example otherwise I cannot say what goes wrong